# Why is the fetch url not updating on button click

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript only project and can't seem to get my fetch api url to update when I click the happy button. I've included my JavaScript below. Any ideas?

I don't know why but stack overflow wants me to write more non code so i'm just blabbing about that to include more text :/

```
let apiUrl = 'https://api.quotable.io/random?tags='
let happyUrl = 'happiness'
let endPoint = '';
let choiceUrl = `${apiUrl}${endPoint}`;
console.log(choiceUrl)

async function quoteOptions() {

  let quoteTypes = document.createElement('div');

  quoteTypes.innerHTML =
    `<div class='container2'>
    <p>Welcome! How are you feeling today?</p>
        <button id="happyBtn">Happy</button>
        <button id="motivationalBtn">Motivational</button>
        <button id="lovedBtn">Loved</button>
        <button id="humorousBtn">Silly</button>
      </div>`

  let content = document.querySelector('.container');
  content.appendChild(quoteTypes)

}
quoteOptions();

async function fetchQuoteOption() {

  try {

    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}${endPoint}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;

    console.log(`Why is ${endPoint} not updating?`);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }

}

document.getElementById("happyBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  let endPoint = 'happiness';

  fetchQuoteOption();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `endPoint` variable is not updating because you actually have two different variables for `endPoint` at different scopes.

You create a new `endPoint` variable inside `myFunction` instead of reassigning the global `endPoint` variable.

Instead of declaring `let endPoint = "happiness";` inside `myFunction`

just reassign the existing **global** endPoint like this:

`endPoint = "happiness"` ...

```
function myFunction() {
  endPoint = "happiness";

  fetchQuoteOption();
}
```

Comment: oof, i know it was something around that variable. You are my hero! Thank you for your help

Comment: Happy to help! Can you please upvote my response and accept the answer if that solved your problem?

Comment: I was able to accept the answer, but can’t upvote yet :) thank you again!